# how to config role management middleware in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have some routes use with middleware

here is one example

```
Route::get('/TobeSubmit', 'AddsController@tobeSubmit')->name('TobeSubmit');
```

when I use this route outside of middleware its working. here is that middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','Admin']],function (){ });
```

when I use that route inside middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','superuser']],function (){
Route::get('/TobeSubmit', 'AddsController@tobeSubmit')->name('TobeSubmit');});
```

like this, its not working, that route use for data retrieving via AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious response would be that the middleware is blocking the request, which in this case would mean that the requestor is not an Admin. Unfortunately we would need more information about the request in order to help you further.

Comment: what you need more